# Rails: User form_for for a post does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to render a text area on a user's profile page to allow them to create a post. At the moment I can view all of a user's posts, but I can't get to their profile page because the form will not render.

I did try to changing some stuff around, but then the form would not post due to a routing error.

I feel like I'm posting to the wrong path but I'm not sure so and advice would be appreciated.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @posts = Post.all
end

def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
        flash[:success] = "Posted!"
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Post could not be submitted"
        redirect_to users_path
    end
end

private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :content)
end
end
```

---

```
_post_form.html.erb

<%= form_for :post, user_posts_path, {method: "create"} do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :content, size: "60x12", placeholder: "What do you want to say?" %>
<%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: When you say the form won't render, do you get any error messages?

Comment: I get this error: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts", :id=>"8"} missing required keys: [:user_id]  I'm not sure what to do with it and where the required key of :user_id is coming from

Comment: How are you passing the User ID to the controller? Via the URL?

Comment: Yes, but the parameter in the url has a key of :id so I'm not sure what is making it look for a :user_id parameter

Comment: Just a hunch, but how is `current_user` created? If it depends on :user_id but only :id is present, it would raise an error when being called.

Comment: Hmm I'm actually not sure. I'm using devise, and I know that is what created the current_user method, but I don't know if that helps answer your question at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123661/discussion-between-jody-heavener-and-harry-b).

Comment: I think there's no such method called `create`.  Try: `method: "post"` in your `form_for`.

Comment: please show your routes.rb file.

you don't need to define a "method" in your form_for

Answer (score 0):

Please check **rake routes** and I think you provided the

```
resources :users do 
  resources :posts
end
```

in routes.eb

so

```
<%= form_for :post, user_posts_path(@user), html: { method: "post"} do |f| %>
```

in controller

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @user = current_user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such HTTP verb called `create`, you need to change the method mentioned in your `form_for`, instead of this:

```
<%= form_for :post, user_posts_path, {method: "create"} do |f| %>
```

try this:

```
<%= form_for :post, user_posts_path, {method: "post"} do |f| %>
```

Comment: when I try this, I end up with this error:    No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts", :id=>"4"} missing required keys: [:user_id]

Comment: @HarryB. you need to fix your routes then.

Comment: shouldn't the nested :posts resources do the trick? I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: create a separate question then, explaining your routes, controller and view setup.